# Prove that every point has been assigned the same number.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, solution-verification, combinatorial-geometry

> Question: Every point in a plane is assigned some real number. It is found that for any triangle, the
>   number at its incenter is the arithmetic mean of numbers at the vertices. Prove that every
>   point has been assigned the same number.

Solution: Let us take any two random points $A$ and $D$ on the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now let us select two points $B$ and $C$ such that $AD||BC, AD<BC$ and $AB=DC$. Also let the real numbers assigned to $A,B,C,D$ be $a,b,c,d$ respectively.

Observe that $ABCD$ is an isosceles trapezium with $AB=DC$.

Now let us produce $BA$ and $CD$ to meet at $E$.

Observe that in $\Delta EAD$, we have $\angle EAD=\angle EDA\implies EA=ED$. Thus we also have $EB=EC$. Hence, $\Delta EAD$ and $\Delta EBC$ are both isosceles triangles with $EA=ED$ and $EB=EC$ respectively.

Let the perpendicular dropped from $E$ to $BC$ meet $BC$ at $F$.

Now consider $\Delta EBD$. $EF$ is the angle bisector of $\angle BED$ and let that the angle bisector of $\angle EBD$ meet $EF$ at $I$. Thus $I$ is the incentre of $\Delta EBD$.

Now consider $\Delta ECA$. $EF$ is the angle bisector of $\angle AEC$. Join $C$ and $I$. Observe that $\Delta EBI$ and $\Delta ECI$ are congruent triangles, which implies that $\angle EBI=\angle ECI=x$ (let).

This implies that $\angle EBI=\angle IBD=x$, which in turn implies that $\angle EBD=
2x$.

Again, $\Delta ADB \cong \Delta DAC\implies \angle DBA=\angle ACD\implies 2x=x+\angle ICA\implies \angle ICA=x.$ Hence, $\angle ICD=\angle ICA=x$, which implies that $CI$ is the angle bisector of $\angle ECA$.

Hence, we can conclude that $I$ is also the incenter of $\Delta ECA$.

Hence the number assigned to $$I=\frac{b+d+e}{3}=\frac{a+c+e}{3}.$$ Thus we have $b+d=c+a$.

Thus, we can conclude that for any random isosceles trapezium $ABCD$ with $AD||BC$ and $AD<BC$ having real numbers $a,b,c,d$ assigned to vertices $A,B,C,D$ respectively, we will have $$a+c=b+d.$$ Let this property be called $\phi$.

Now select any two random points $A'$ and $B'$ on the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and construct a regular pentagon $A'B'C'D'E'$. Let the real number assigned to $A',B',C',D',E'$ be $a',b',c',d',e'$ respectively.

Now $B'C'E'D'$ is an isosceles trapezium, hence by $\phi$, we have $b'+d'=e'+c'$. Similarly, $e'+c'=a'+d'$, $a'+c'=b'+d'$ and $b'+e'=a'+d'$. From these four equations we can conclude that $a'=b'=c'=d'=e'$.

Thus we have $a'=b'$. From here, we can conclude that, since $A$ and $B$ were randomly chosen, therefore, we can reach to the same conclusion, i.e, $a'=b'$, with any other pair of points $\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Hence, we can conclude that every point on the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ has been assigned the same number.

Is this solution correct and is there a better solution than this one?

Comment: Take a look at https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2001_USAMO_Problems/Problem_6 and https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/USAMO2001_6.shtml