Prove that there is a circle inscribed in the quadrilateral $QCMD$.
The problem
a) Consider the isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$, with bases $AB$
and $CD$, so that $AB > CD$. Let ${Q} = AC \cap BD$ and ${M} = AD \cap BC$.
Prove that there is a circle inscribed in the quadrilateral $QCMD$.
b) Each point in the plane is associated with a real number, so that
for any triangle, let the number corresponding to the circle inscribed in it be
equal to the arithmetic mean of the numbers corresponding to the vertices of the triangle,
Prove that all points of the plane have been assigned the same number.
(
Each point of the plan is associated with a number. We can choose 3 points (A, B,C), so we have a triangle, and the circle inscribed in this triangle. We can associate a number to this circle, which is the mean of the values associated with (A, B,C). What is not clearly said, is that this circle is also associated with infinite number of other triangles (D,E,F) for example. And no matter which triangle we choose, if the circle inscrite is the same, the average of the 3 values associated to the 3 vertices is the same.
)
my idea
I have been able to do the first point:

So, we know that there is a circle inscribed in the quadrilateral QCMD if and only if $QC+DM=DQ+MC$, which is true because of the similarity in triangle $DMC$ with $AMB$ and $DQC$ with $BQA$ and because $DA=BC$.
Hope one of you can help me solve b). Thanks!

Please check this out:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664117/prove-that-every-point-has-been-assigned-the-same-number

@Soheil Thanksss...but still is point a) right solved?

You're welcome! Actually, I'm not sure if I understand your approach correctly.  You are right that we should prove $QC+DM=DQ+MC$. But I'm not sure how you prove it using the similarity of those two pairs of triangles.

Note that if two triangles are similar, if sides of the first triangle are $a,b,c$, then the sides of the other triangle are $ka, kb, kc$. Did you use it?

@Soheil Look at my edit, there was a misspelling, sorry

@Soheil Now my solution is ok?

Sorry I did not understand how you deduced $QC+DM=DQ+MC$ from those similar triangles. Can you please elaborate?

You have 2 distinct questions, and should make 2 distinct posts. (At this point, you might as well delete b, since you now know that it's USAMO 2001/6. Then add a solution-verification tag).
